# Html5 Canvas to Canvas Blit

Tags: html, canvas, blit

I need to set up a background canvas with a load of images drawn on at various places. Nothing changes on this background, so I want to do it all at once. I think I know how to do that. Then each frame I want to copy that background canvas (ultimately just a part of it) to my main screen canvas people see.

I am doing the following:

```
g_CanvasScreen = document.getElementById("m_Canvas");
g_CanvasScreenContext = g_CanvasScreen.getContext("2d");

g_OffScreenBackground = document.createElement("canvas");
g_OffScreenBackgroundContext = g_CanvasScreen.getContext("2d");
```

I believe this gets the main screen canvas from the hmtl5 page g_CanvasScreen.

I believe g_OffScreenBackground is a newly created canvas in memory.

Once all images have loaded I then draw all the images in the correct places to the background screen by calling the function:

```
DrawMapToBackground(g_OffScreenBackground, g_OffScreenBackgroundContext, 2000, 1600);
```

2000 x 1600 is the size of the offscreen background.

This then leads to the thing I am not sure about. I believe this will blit the background canvas to the main screen:

```
g_CanvasScreenContext.drawImage(g_OffScreenBackground,
    0, 0, g_OffScreenBackground.width, g_OffScreenBackground.height,
    screenX, screenY, g_OffScreenBackground.width, g_OffScreenBackground.height);
```

Is this last function correct? Can I do a canvas to canvas blit? Should I be doing this another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of redrawing the background each time,  just put 2 canvas’s on top of each other.

First draw the background image once on the bottom canvas.

Then use the top canvas to draw all your “changing” drawings.

Here’s code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/pSjEt/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
#container{
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid blue;
  width:500px;
  height:300px;
}
.subcanvs{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var bk=document.getElementById("background");
    var bkCtx=bk.getContext("2d");
    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var bkimg=new Image();
    bkimg.onload=function(){
      bk.width=bkimg.width;
      bk.height=bkimg.height;
      canvas.width=bkimg.width;
      canvas.height=bkimg.height;
      bkCtx.drawImage(bkimg,0,0);
      draw();
    }
    bkimg.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/skyGrass.png";

    var x=50;

    function draw(){
        x+=5;
        if(x>300){x=50;}
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x,100,30,0,Math.PI*2,false);
        ctx.strokeStyle="gold";
        ctx.fillStyle="yellow";
        ctx.lineWidth=5;
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fill();
        setTimeout(draw,1000);
    }

});   // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
      <canvas id="background" class="subcanvs"></canvas>
      <canvas id="canvas" class="subcanvs"></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This looks like a clever idea, but unfortunately my front and back canvases have to rotate.

Comment: ...and also ultimately it will only be part of the background image being drawn, depending on where the player's sprite is on the screen.

Comment: Fair enough.  BTW, the last 4 arguments of your drawimage are used to move and scale the offscreen canvas as it is being drawn to the foreground image. By providing screenX and screenY you are actually moving the background image to that coordinate on the main canvas (the main canvas will have no background left of screenX or above screenY).  If you don't need to move and scale, just leave the last 4 arguments off.

Comment: Thanks once again for your help. I managed to get my version running (find a stripped down version here http://jsfiddle.net/jaa17/RGmx6/ ) ... However, I like the way you are doing it a lot more, and might try and mod your way to take into account the rotations. Thanks again.